# Change CSS based on certain DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hoping someone could help me with a bit of jquery or javascript. I have some DIV's that contain the values of a checkbox being either "1" or "0" depending on whether I check the box or not:

```
<div class="checkbox">1</div>   //This is when the checkbox is checked

<div class="checkbox">0</div>   //This is when the checkbox is NOT checked
```

The class for this DIV stays the same whether it is a 0 or a 1 so I need to have a conditional statement that says,

"If the contents of the DIV is 1 then show it"

AND

"If the contents of the DIV is 0, then hide it"

Would this be simple to do?

Comment: It would be better to give another class to each element, like "when-checked" for one and "when-not-checked" for the other. Having to look in the DOM at the contents is messy and slower (though performance probably won't be a real problem here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filter would come in handy for such case..

```
$('.checkbox').filter(function () {
   return $(this).text() == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: What if it changes after this filter runs

Comment: Put it inside a change listener like my answer. I'd combine mine and Vega's answers (though his deserves the Answer)

Comment: @idrumgood, disagree. Yours doesn't run unless an event has been triggered

Comment: This works great thanks guys, I am noticing that the "0" shows up just briefly before the script runs and then it disappears. Is there anyway to stop that? I have the script at the bottom of the page...it doesn't work when placed at the top.

Comment: If you need it to run on page load AND when checkboxes change, then you're going to want to take this filter code, put it in a function, then call that function both on page load and on a change listener.

Comment: @Dan You can change it so with CSS all your `.checkbox` are set to `display: none;` and then alter this javascript to `.show()` instead of `.hide()`. Though then you'll have a similar flash where there's nothing and then one of them.

Comment: The checkbox value isn't going to change. Once the page loads, it will be a 0 or a 1.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it differently.

```
$("input#checkbox").change(function(){
  $("div.checkbox").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Considering that your checkbox is the one that it is altering the content of the `<div>` anyways.

Comment: I think he want to show the `div.checkbox` with text content `1` and hide `div.checkbox` with text content `0`

Comment: I agree with your answer in that regard and you were faster than me though

Answer (score 0):

Any time a checkbox is changed, look at your divs with class `checkbox` and if they have 1, show, else hide.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('.checkbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() === '1'){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: While mine works, @Vega 's answer is much cleaner and does the same thing as my `.each()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If i have to do it then i would love to do in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/P2WmG/

```
var chktxt = $.trim($('.checkbox').text());
if (chktxt == 0) {
   $('#checkbox').hide();
} else {
   $('#checkbox').show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select the divs based on their contents.

```
$('div.checkbox:contains("1")').show();
$('div.checkbox:contains("0")').hide();
```

Comment: Contains should be used with extreme care to prevent false-positives

Comment: Agreed, but Dan specified that the contents are only either "1" or "0" so you'd be hard pressed to get false positives.